# function_exists fatal error

Tags: php, funções, classes

Olá, preciso de ajuda para solucionar esse problema.

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código (coloquei o numero da linha para facilitar):

```
**186** if ( function_exists( self::$function_val() ) === TRUE ){
**187**    call_user_func( self::$function_val() );
**188** }
```

Mas aparece o seguinte erro na tela:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Widgets::contacts() in /var/www/html/ui/includes/class_widgets.php on line 186

A função Widgets::contacts() realmente não existe, mas o objetivo do function_exists não é justamente verificar isso e só retornar TRUE ou FALSE??

Comment: Ele está dizendo que você está utilizando um método indefinido, não uma função, por isso ta retornando erro.

Comment: Qual o valor de `self::$function_val`? É uma string?

Comment: tenho impressão de que está confundindo com method_exists()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se vai trabalhar com métodos *(propriedades da classe)*, o ideal mesmo é usar `method_exists` em vez de `function_exists`.

```
<?php

class A
{
    static function mostra(){
        return;
    }

    private function esconde(){
        return;
    }

    public function existe($metodo){
        if(method_exists($this, $metodo)){
            print "existe: Existe<br>";
        } else {
            print "existe: Nao existe<br>";
        }
    }

    public function existe_metodo($metodo){
        if(function_exists($metodo)){
            print "existe_metodo: Existe<br>";
        } else {
            print "existe_metodo: Não existe<br>";
        }
    }
}

$p = new A;

$p->existe('esconde');
$p->existe_metodo('esconde');
```

Por outro lado:

```
function qualquer(){
    return;
}

if(function_exists('qualquer')){
    print "Sou a funcao 'qualquer' e existo<br>";
}
```

No seu exemplo, o que acontece, é que você está a procurando por um método inexistente, vai retornar sempre erro, porque você está usando o operador `::`*(scope resolution operator)*, isso não se limita a verificar, tenta também aceder o próprio método, daí o *undefined method*. O correcto seria você usar o `method_exists` como nos exemplos, fornecendo o nome do objecto e o método que se quer verificar quer seja estático ou não.

> - **function_exists** - procura apenas na lista de funções definidas tanto    pelo usuário como as internas.
> - **method_exists** - procura pelo método tendo como base o objecto indicado no primeiro parâmetro.

Answer (score 1):

Você está confundindo algumas coisas. A função `function_exists` recebe uma `string` que seria o nome da função para poder avaliar se uma função com  aquele nome existe ou não.

No seu caso, quando você está chamando `self::$function_val()` está pedindo para o PHP fazer uma chamada dinâmica de um método estático presente em `self`, porém usando um valor variável presente em `$function_val`.

Ou seja:

```
$function_val = 'method';

Test::$function_val();
```

Seria equivalente a:

```
 Test::method();
```

No seu exemplo, é como você estivesse invocando o método para trazer o resultado para ser verificado com `function_exists`, mas  dá pra perceber que essa não foi sua intenção.

Para checar a existência de um método para chamá-lo, você deveria usar `method_exists`.

```
if (method_exists(get_called_class(), $function_val)) {

}
```

Se estiver usando o PHP 5.5 ou maior, você pode trocar `get_called_class()` por `static::class` ou `self::class`.

Answer (score 0):

Se o `self::$function_val` estiver recebendo uma `string` com o nome de uma função e creio que o `call_user_func` seja desnecessário (na verdade errado), ao fazer isto `self::$function_val()` você já esta chamando a variavel com função e então o `call_user_func` está tentando executar o retorno da função e não a função

Então faça isto (o `=== TRUE` realmente é redundante eu removi):

```
if ( function_exists( self::$function_val ) ){
    self::$function_val();
}
```

Se estiver recebendo coisas várias como métodos, closures, funções pode usar `is_callable`:

```
if ( is_callable( self::$function_val ) ){
    self::$function_val();
}
```

**Acaso** a chamada `self::$function_val()` realmente retorne outra função você colocar de volta o `call_user_func`.

Answer (score -2):

A função "function_exists" deve receber o nome da função como string, no seu exemplo você está passando a função como parâmetro.

```
if ( function_exists( 'nome_da_funcao' ) ) {
     call_user_func( self::$function_val() );
}
```